# htaccess doesn't work on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just started playing with URL rewriting today and I watched/read a few tutorials but I still don't really get how this rewriting works.

I created a `.htaccess` file and placed it in my root directory.
I'm currently working on my local machine, using Apache.

I want `http://localhost:5216/index.php` to redirect to `http://localhost:5216/index`

In my .htaccess file I have the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php
```

This doesn't work. I tried refreshing the page, I checked that `httpd.conf` file has `AllowOverride All` selected. 
I've read a few tutorials and I think I do this the right way but it seems like I don't. What is wrong with my file?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and my solution was this (note that I use Laragon with WAMP).
It has nothing to do with invidual htaccess files, they are all ignored because of this part in Apache's httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/laragon/www"
<Directory "D:/laragon/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So you need to locate your httpd.conf and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Your .htaccess files should execute now.

Answer (score 0):

> I want `http://localhost:5216/index.php` to redirect to `http://localhost:5216/index`
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php
> ```

Your `RewriteRule` actually does the opposite... it rewrites from `/index` (or `/inde` since you've made the last `x` optional) to `index.php`. Note that this is an *internal rewrite*, not an *external redirect*.

Your `RewriteRule` is close to what you probably want to do. This allows you to link to `/index` (in your application) and still serve the actual `/index.php` file.

---

Taking this a step further... Say you had a *contact* document called "contact-the-monster.php" in the document root - this is the physical file on your filesystem. But you wanted to use the simple URL `/contact` to access this document - this is the URL that you would use throughout your application. You don't want any user to see the filename "contact-the-monster.php". Then in your root `.htaccess` file you need to *internally rewrite* all requests to `/contact` to `/contact-the-monster.php`, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact-the-monster.php [L]
```

The `L` (`LAST`) flag is included since you probably don't need to do anything else.

---

Make sure that `MultiViews` is not enabled. This can be disabled in `.htaccess` using the `Options` directive:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

`MultiViews` can conflict with mod_rewrite to produce unexpected results. Particularly when your URL maps to a file less the file extension.

Comment: So it should look like this?
RewriteRule  ^index index.php

Comment: That would be OK, although I would add an end of string anchor (`$`) to the pattern. ie. `RewriteRule ^index$ index.php`. Otherwise it would match `/index-anything`. You have to be careful of rewrite/redirect loops, although you should be OK in this instance. I've updated my answer with another example.

Comment: I've tried it the way you showed me. I've also checked some other tutorials  and it still doesn't work. 
I wrote this 

RewriteRule  ^index index.php [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) profile.php?username=$1 [NC]


None of these two work. htaccess file should be in the root directory (where all my .php and .html files are), is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does anything happen? Do you get a 404? Have you confirmed that .htaccess files are being processed? If you include some _rubbish_ on the first line, do you get an error?

Comment: Checking it right now. I think htaccess file is being ignored by apache. I don't get any errors, the page loads without any problem.

Comment: No idea what's wrong. Nothing happens even if I break htaccess files intentionally.

Comment: "I don't get any errors" - If you have _nonsense_ in your .htaccess file and you get no error then it's not being read at all - as you say, it is being ignored. "the page loads without any problem" - however, neither should the "page load without any problem" if you are requesting one of your "pretty" URLs. Also, make sure `MultiViews` is not enabled, or disable this in `.htaccess` - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121670/discussion-between-davidb-and-w3dk).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have faced the same problem and thought that there is no solution at all can help but i found this tiny line of code which make the magic.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Add it to the first line of your .htaccess file and everything should work like a charm. Thanks for sharing.